# How to prevent item text wrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

Here's my code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="img/avatar-small.jpg">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Alissa Connor said something</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit </p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[And what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exBsq.jpg)

[image: And what I get]

I maybe use the wrong element to do this, but I would like to see the whole text.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic has a predefined style for that. Use `text-wrap` on your ion-item (or class `item-text-wrap` in Ionic 1):

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="img/avatar-small.jpg">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Alissa Connor said something</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit </p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
just provide some idea for this issue. i didn't test this.

.word-wrap {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

<p class="word-wrap">Sed ut perspicia.....</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

white-space: nowrap; in the css on the appropriate class.

If you would like it to wrap, then white-space: wrap;

But if it could also be your div container that is cutting it off because there are too many words, with too big of a font size to fit all the text on one line. You either have to make the container bigger for the text to fit or you are going to have to wrap the text.